# Why does the EPIC eclipse plugin not show any info in "Explain Errors/Warnings"?

Tags: perl, eclipse, plugins, epic

I use the "EPIC" plugin to Eclipse for Perl development, but in the "Explain Errors/Warnings" view there's no info at all, even though I have some compilation errors. Do I need to do anything special to get EPIC to display useful info in that view? What is that view for anyway?

Answer (score 3):

The view isn't populated automatically. As the [user's guide says](http://www.epic-ide.org/guide/ch05s02.php) (which is excellent btw), you have to right click the warning/error and select "Explain Errors/Warnings" from the context menu. You have to click the icon though, not the code that is producing the error.

The view will give you a lot more details and advice than the error message or warning itself.