# Are there any decent Perl plugins for Eclipse?

Tags: perl, eclipse, epic

I'm using EPIC, but it seems to have some drawbacks. Are there any other Perl plugins for Eclipse?

Comment: In the "Problems" view, i have two messages that literally say just this: "...propagated in c:/perl/lib/base.pm line 93". 
I'd like a bit more than that. I need more information to fix the problem. Also "Explain\Errors and Warnings" view doesn't seem to do anything: totally blank, allows no input.

Comment: Another puzzling behavior: Normally in Eclipse, a little red icon on the file name means there's a compilation problem. When you open the file, a red icon appears on the appropriate line(s). But with EPIC I get the former but not the latter. It doesn't pinpoint the problematic line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There does not seem to be any other serious eclipse plugin for Perl out there, aside EPIC.

Regarding the problematic behaviors, did you check the question [Why does the EPIC eclipse plugin not show any info in “Explain Errors/Warnings”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373282) and its associated [EPIC user guide](http://www.epic-ide.org/guide/ch05s02.php) ?

Answer (score 0):

A new plugin is Perlipse http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewlink-cid-1133.html
It is far from complete atm.

Answer (score 0):

For those who find this after me, ...propagated seems to appear for me when importing a module that isn't in the perl path using quotes. For example:

```
use base qw/ Class::DBI /;
```

This shows up as an error in the project explorer and problems window but not in the perl module itself.